# URLs in portlets

Tags: java, servlets, portlet

Hi guys can you tell me about URL in portlets. For example if i have `myPortlet.java` what i gonna do to call it from html form? I have to write line

```
<portlet-class>test.myPortlet</portlet-class>
```

in `portlet.xml`.

Im understand that in form i gonna use `actionURL` but how to build it?
Another question: Another java classes calls in portlet like in servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what do you want your portlet to do, you may use different URLs:

- To trigger a call to `processAction()` method (thus change the state of your portlet), use the action URL. In a JSP included to your portlet's view you can obtain it by calling `<portlet:actionURL />`. In portlet code, one can get the URL by calling `RenderResponse.createActionURL()`
- To get a URL that triggers a render request, use `<portlet:renderURL/>`. This will trigger a render of the portlet. Java API alternative is to call `RenderResponse.createRenderURL()`
- If your portlet is a JSR-286 (portlet 2.0) compliant one, you can also use the `<portlet:resourceURL />` tag to get a URL that triggers a call to  `serverResource()` of your portlet. Similary to the above, there is also `RenderResponse.createResourceURL()`.

All of the portlet tags belong to the portlet tag library - include it with `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>`, and call `<portlet:defineObjects />` on the top of your JSP).

Calls to `RenderResponse.create*Url()` methods return a `PortletURL` class and doing a `toString()` on them produces a string representation of the URL that can be included in markup produced by the portlet.

Both the portlet tags and `PortletURL` instances also allow to specify portlet mode and window state to use to render the responses (either by tag attributes or by setters defined in the `PortletURL` class).

For more, please see the [spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286).